# Core Plot label alignment

Tags: ios, core-plot

i'm using custom labels in horizontal bar chart with core plot.
Is it possible to align these labels in center of the bar? IN bar not ON bar ;-)

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a negative `labelOffset` to move the labels inside the bars, although this will place them a fixed distance from the bar tips. It's not too difficult to make your own labels using `CPTTextLayer` and plot space annotations if you need to center the labels between the ends of the bars, too.

Comment: exists an example for plot space annotations?

Comment: Several of the demos in the *Plot Gallery* example app use plot space annotations to label points in a scatter plot. This will work with any X-Y plot. Use the `contentAnchorPoint`, `displacement`, and `rotation` properties to position the content layer relative to the annotation's anchor point.